# Is it possible to force Node.js to JIT compile code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

Since Node.js uses the V8 js engine, I imagine it works the same way as v8 does and only optimizes/jit compiles a function or some piece of code when it is CPU intensive or gets called many times over.

Considering I'm making a server and I want to get the best performance possible out of my code, and that memory isn't a problem, would there be a way to "force" all my code to be JIT compiled and optimized for performance from the moment it first runs?

Comment: In general, the JIT is much better than you at optimising the code that needs it. Notice that not memory is the problem, but also compile time - your server would be much slower to start up if it would need to compile the complete code of the whole application. Especially given that a lot of code does actually run only once.

Comment: how slow is much slower though? Because in my case, I think that even seconds to start wouldn't matter that much, as it would only need to happen once

Answer (score 24, accepted):

V8 developer here. You get the best possible performance by letting V8 do its thing. (We care a lot about performance, and we build V8 such that the out-of-the-box configuration is what gives you the best possible performance.)

For testing purposes, there is indeed a flag that forces "optimized" compilation of all code on first execution. But "optimized" really needs to be in quotes there, because doing so means **significantly *lower* performance** than you would normally get. The reason is not only compile time, but also the fact that for a dynamic language like JavaScript, creating optimized code **critically depends** on observing type feedback first. You *can* feed code without type feedback to the optimizing compiler, but it won't be able to do a good job -- it has two choices: either produce generic code that can handle any type (which will be about as fast as non-optimized code), or produce code that makes random guesses about which types it'll encounter (which means there's an almost 100% chance that *some* guess will be wrong and the code will have to be thrown away on first execution). Either way, the resulting performance is worse than the regular way of doing things.

If you want to be able to optimize code ahead of time, write your server in C++, or Rust, or Go, etc. ;-)